# Using Static Visibility Enum as Command Parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums

Okay, so, this problem seems embarrassingly simple, but somehow I can't figure it out so, I'm gonna ask it anyway...

I wanna use `Visibility` this way in the `CommandParameter` of `KeyBinding` (pay attention for `<!--THIS LINE-->` section):

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System"
    ...>
...
<Window.InputBindings>
</Window.InputBindings>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MainWindowVM}">
    ...
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray">
        <ScrollViewer.InputBindings>
        ...
            <!--THIS LINE--><KeyBinding Key="OemOpenBrackets" Command="{Binding EditLeftBarLineVisibilityCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Static sys:Visibility.Visible}"/>
            <!--THIS LINE--><KeyBinding Key="OemCloseBrackets" Command="{Binding EditRightBarLineVisibilityCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Static sys:Visibility.Visible}"/>
        </ScrollViewer.InputBindings>
        ...
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

But, it seemed that :

> The name "Visibility" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:System;assembly=System"

I have look for `Visibility` in my VM and it's located in `System.Windows`, but I can't find that on XAML, above (`System`) is the closest one I found and it turned out not good.

Anyone knows what namespace to be used in XAML? (There's no `System.Windows` in the XAML listed though, and if it turns out I haven't referenced it, my VM can't use it as well right?)

Or, is it necessary to use `ObjectDataProvider` only for `System` `Enum`? (Since I can seamlessly do this without `ObjectDataProvider` if it's my own custom enum)

P.S. MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Nothing is "embarrassingly simple" with WPF, especially when Commands are involved. :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard WPF namespaces are mapped to the default XML namespace (`http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation`), so you don't need any prefix:

```
CommandParameter="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"
```